# No defined boundaries of different artboards

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, artboard

My artboards in illustrator have disappeared and now it is one large square. When I go into artboard mode it shows the individual artboards however when I switch back it goes back to the large white square.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try going to `View → Show Artboards` in the main menu, or use this shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (on PC).

Answer (score 0):

Also try going to `Main Menu → Window → Artboards` — this should list all the existing artboards used in your document. You can click around on this list, jump between artboards and see where each one is, and what they include.